# How to organize three different loops by id

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, sorting, e-commerce

I have created a functioning e-commerce platform where Members can buy/view books. Everything works fine, But I would like to organize all of the Books in my Index Page by Book_Id.

Currently I have 3 Arrays displaying different information based on Book Availability and a Members Purchased or Unpurchased Books. How can I combine these arrays, or organize them by BOOK_ID.

**Ex.**

```
Total Books = 10

5 Available Books {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

3 Books Purchased {6, 8, 9}

2 Coming Soon Books {7, 10}

Can I somehow organize the arrays by id {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
```

**MODELS**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :member

  has_many :books, through: :orders
  has_many :orders, :dependent => :destroy

  ###Users purchased books
  def purchased_books
    books
  end

  def unavailable_unpurchased_books
    Book.unavailable.where("id not in (?)", purchased_issues.pluck(:issue_id))
  end
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :book_id, :order_date, :user_id

  belongs_to :publisher
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :book

end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :publisher_id, :description, :pages, :title, :available_in, :price, :release_date

  has_many :orders
  has_many :users, through: :orders

  scope :unavailable,->{where("release_date > ?",Date.today)}
  scope :available,->{where("release_date < ?",Date.today)

end
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
def index
  @available_books = Book.available.where(:publisher_id => @publisher.id)
  @orders = current_user.orders
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json  { render :json => @issues }
  end
end
```

**VIEWS**

```
<% if current_user.member? %>

 ###HOW CAN I ORGANIZE THESE INTO 1 BY BOOK_ID

  ###Shows All Available Books
  <% @available_books.each do |book| %> 
    <%= book.title %>
  <% end %>

  ###Shows Books Bought By Member
  <% @orders.each do |order| %>
    <%= order.book.title %>
  <% end %>

  ###Shows All Books Not Available or Coming Soon
  <% current_user.unavailable_unpurchased_books do |book| %>
    <%= book.title %>
  <% end %>


<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but how about...

controller...

```
@available_books = Book.available.where(:publisher_id => @publisher.id)
@ordered_books = current_user.books
@not_available = current_user.unavailable_unpurchased_books
@all_books = @available_books + @ordered_books + @not_available
@all_books.sort!{|x| x.id}
```

You may need some helper methods to show which books are in which categories on the view

Comment: I am curious, once all arrays are placed in @all_books, can one create a switch statement so that I can customize how each array is being displayed?

Comment: The idea is that you would display one array. You could create a helper method or a model method to control appearance... like book.available?(@publisher) and book.unavailable? (current_user) and book.ordered? (current_user) those methods eould look like for example def available?(pub);Book.available.where(publisher_id: pub id).include?(self); end